# Вопрос: Koala не переходит на русский язык

Tags: scss

Установил сегодня Koala, чтобы внедрять SCSS  в проекты. Столкнулся с проблемами настройки: при выборе русского языка в настройках приложение на русский не переключается, а при повторном входе в настройки снова стоит английский.

И хотелось бы узнать, есть ли возможность как-то изменить название папки, в которую компилятся SCSS-файлы (заменить stylesheets на css, например).

P.S. У меня Windows 7 SP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу смены названия директории со скомпилеными стилями - это можно сделать в файле config.rb  в корне проекта. Нужно изменить строку

```
css_dir = "css"
```

Первая часть вопроса в силе.

Answer (score 0):

Настройки - Основные - Язык: Русский - ОК - Закрыть Koala [x] - Открыть Koala
 - Profit. Мне помогло.

[image: Русификация]